# What could be the explanation of this 'pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError'?

Tags: python, hdfs, pyarrow

I'm working on an HDP cluster and I'm trying to read a **.csv** file from HDFS using **pyarrow**. I am able to connect to hdfs and print information about the file using the **info()** function. But when it comes to reading the content of the file, I get a **pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError**. What could be the source of the problem?

Here is the code I am executing

```py
# IMPORTS
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import csv
import os
import subprocess

# GET HDFS CLASSPATH
classpath = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/bin/hdfs", "classpath", "--glob"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

# CONFIGURE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"] = "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client"
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/home/G60070/installs/jdk1.8.0_201/"
os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = classpath.decode("utf-8")
os.environ["ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR"] = "/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/usr/lib/"

# USING PYARROW
## connect to hdfs
fs = pa.hdfs.connect("xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.fr", 8020)
file = 'hdfs://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.fr:8020/user/F43479/trip_data_v2.csv'
print(str(fs.info(file))) # this instruction works well

## read csv file
csv_file = csv.read_csv(file) # this one doesn't work as expected
csv_file
```

According to the [pyarrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html#reading-csv-files), I'm supposed to get the **list of the csv's columns** as a result.

But I'm getting this error:
**pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Failed to open local file: hdfs://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.fr:8020/user/F43479/trip_data_v2.csv, error: file not found**

First, I thought I miswrote the filepath. I checked hdfs and the file is there.

```
[F43479@xxxxx dask_tests]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/F43479/
Found 9 items
-rw-r-----   3 F43479 hdfs            0 2019-03-07 16:42 /user/F43479/-
drwx------   - F43479 hdfs            0 2019-04-03 02:00 /user/F43479/.Trash
drwxr-x---   - F43479 hdfs            0 2019-03-13 16:53 /user/F43479/.hiveJars
drwxr-x---   - F43479 hdfs            0 2019-03-13 16:52 /user/F43479/hive
drwxr-x---   - F43479 hdfs            0 2019-03-15 13:23 /user/F43479/nyctaxi_trip_data
-rw-r-----   3 F43479 hdfs           36 2019-04-15 11:13 /user/F43479/test.csv
-rw-r-----   3 F43479 hdfs  50486731416 2019-03-26 17:37 /user/F43479/trip_data.csv
-rw-r-----   3 F43479 hdfs   5097056230 2019-04-15 13:57 /user/F43479/trip_data_v2.csv
-rw-r-----   3 F43479 hdfs 504867312828 2019-04-02 11:15 /user/F43479/trip_data_x10.csv
```

What could be the source of the problem?

Thanks for your potential help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the file through `HadoopFileSystem` object:

```
with fs.open(file, 'rb') as f:
    ## read csv file
    csv_file = csv.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: I went to see the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#hadoop-file-system-hdfs) about **fs.open()**. What I understood is that this function uses a **C++-based interface** enabling pyarrow to connect to **Hadoop File System**. 
But, by default pyarrow uses **libhdfs**, a JNI-based Interface to Java Hadoop Client, to interact with HDFS. The path to **libhdfs** is defined in the env variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** (which I had configured). 
Did my error occur becauz pyarrow wasn't able to access hdfs using its default behaviour?

Comment: In `csv.read_csv(file)` the `file` variable is the string `'hdfs://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.fr:8020/user/F43479/trip_data_v2.csv'`. While you had created the `fs` filesystem object `csv.read_csv` is not aware of it. I think the error message could be better